# jQuery Animate Toggle - Animation only works on second click

Tags: jquery-animate, hide, slide, jquery

**Task:** I wanted to create a simple **share button** which extends to a share section *(F,T,G,P)* when clicked.

I failed to let the section slide out of the **share button** - *what I really, really wanted* - but managed to let a separate `ul` element slide out on the right side.

The animation worked… *until* I set the `ul` to hide initially via `$('.networks').hide();`

The sections is intended to only show up after a click, but now after the first click it just "pops open" ignoring the configured slide-out. Sliding only works in both directions *(open and close)* after clicking on it at least once .

I've uploaded an Example **[here at Codepen.io](http://codepen.io/pattulus/full/ufbsJ)** and as a **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pattulus/Ez4rx/)**.

---

**Side note:** the demos are behaving a little bit strange since they *appear* to only show a slide-in fx. The slide-out fx, with which we start, always looks like it pops open - that's not the case, it works after the second click, so you got to focus your eyes to see it (on a normal browser it *visibly* works better).

---

**PS:** Bonus points if you help me make this slide out of the "share" button. Be aware that I only have rudimentary knowledge of Javascript ( * duck and run * ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this fiddle [link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GKemc).

I changed the display property of the buttons to be inline-block instead of inline.
Elements with display inline can not have a width and i think it was the reason why jQuery was not able to animates the Elements width. I also animated the wrap around the ul instead of the ul.

EDIT: made a fast mockup of the thing sliding out of the button. Changed some css to be on the list elements itself instead of on the a elements, just work through the css and I think it will look ok. 
edit forgot the link: [link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ljfxF)

Comment: What can I say more: Perfect. Thanks a lot buddy. I've been pondering about this the whole weekend and couldn't get my head around it. I'd never have guess that changing inline to inline-block will fix the issues I got with my attempt. Now even the slide-out functionality I was looking for works properly (thanks for the mockup too).